# Load flat file with dynamic columns into sql server table

Tags: sql-server

I need to load flat files which has dynamic columns (columns are not fixed they change sometimes). How do I create a stored procedure which loads these flat files into sql table. These are files are nearly 100 and seat in one location.

Answer (score 0):

it only an idea!!!

ok so you have  files looking like this;

```
case 1
col1;col2;col3;col4;col5
1;s;c;2;3
4;s;c;7;3

case 2
col1;col2;col3;col4
2;p;2;3
2;s;7;3

case 3
col1;col2;col3
1;p;2
20;s;7

I Step

1- read the file and get only the header into a table
exple:
Table_my_dyn_header contains 
in case 1: col1;col2;col3;col4;col5
in case 2: col1;col2;col3;col4
2- save the file header into a variable (its not a must)
 you would get in case 1 :  col1;col2;col3;col4;col5
 or  case 2 :  col1;col2;col3;col4

 3-transform the header you get in  variables
  in cas 2 'col1;col2;col3;col4' would become 
  col1 -> variable 1
  col2
  col3
  col4 -> variable 4
  4- so with those new variables you can build you control-file dynamically 
  ( with cursor or for-iteration)

  II Step reload the data-file because you have your control file build
```